# Laravel - Update always throws "MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

From my research, this error is related to a routing error. As this error is thrown regardless of the code I utilize in my update function, that makes sense.

However I believe all my routes/forms are proper:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('orders/edit/{order}', 'OrderController@edit')->name('orders.edit');
Route::patch('orders/update', 'OrderController@update')->name('orders.update');
```

**OrderController.php**

```
public function edit(Order $order)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $meals = DB::table('products')
              ->leftJoin('order_product', function ($join) use ($order) {
                  $join->on('products.id', '=', 'order_product.product_id')
                       ->where('order_product.order_id', '=', $order->id);
              })
              ->select('products.*', 'order_product.qty')
              ->get();

    return view('orders.edit', compact('order', 'products', 'meals'));
}

public function update(Request $request,Order $order)
{
    //doesnt seem to matter what is in here but this is my return
    return redirect()->route('orders.checkout', $order->id);
}
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'orders.update', 'method' => 'patch']) !!}
    {{ Form::text('coupon', $order->coupon) }} // sample of an input I am using
    {{ Form::submit('Place Order') }}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**UPDATE**

per the suggestion of @rpm192, I attempted:

`{!! Form::open(['action' => ['orders.update', $order->id], 'method' => 'patch']) !!}`

but then when loading the `edit.blade.php`, it throws me...

`Action App\Http\Controllers\orders.update not defined. (View: /Users/now/Public/keto/resources/views/orders/edit.blade.php)`

so I then tried...

`{!! Form::open(['action' => ['OrderController@update', $order->id], 'method' => 'patch']) !!}`

but that throws me...

`Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\OrderController::update(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected`

assuming this is the correct method as I am now getting closer to the solution, what additional argument is it looking for?

Comment: Try changing: `'route' => 'orders.update'` to: `'action' => ['orders.update', $order->id]`

Comment: @rpm192, I have attempted your suggestion and have updated my question with my results.

Comment: HTML forms do not support put/patch/delete methods so you have to spoof them:  <form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>

Comment: Can you add the `edit` method / function from your controller?

Comment: @rpm192, I have added the `edit` method to my question. @brad, that should be handled by the `'method' => 'patch'` used with the Laravel Collective package I am utilizing.

Comment: See my answer below and tell me if it makes a difference.

Comment: @sgt_disco I've used the same package in all my previous and current projects but I always go with the hidden input, don't know why but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller requires both the request and the ID of the order (so it knows which one to update).

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['OrderController@update', $order->id], 'method' => 'post']) !!} // modified this
    {{ Form::text('coupon', $order->coupon) }}

    {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT') }} // added this

    {{ Form::submit('Place Order') }}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

If that doesn't work, try again by modifying your route:

```
// from
Route::patch('orders/update', 'OrderController@update')->name('orders.update');

// to
Route::post('orders/update/{order}', 'OrderController@update')->name('orders.update');
```

Comment: so that threw me the error on the blade that `OrderController@update` isn't a route. so I  substituting it with `orders.update` which is the route name, but it brings me back to the original error. I also attempted swapping the `route` with `action` in the `Form::open` with this new hidden input setup but that again throws me the original error.

Comment: Figured it out! In addition to this, I also have to change my route to include {order} like so: `Route::any('orders/update/{order}','OrderController@update')->name('orders.update');` Thanks so much @rpm192